# How to send a message/share object to other friend's wall with Facebook Android SDK?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-sdk-3.0

I'm trying to share and object (text, image, caption ...) and a custom message to other friend's wall.

I've found this tutorial to feed my own wall:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/feed-dialog/

I'm looking exactly the same but allowing user to choose from his friends list who is going to receive this post.

Also, this is a WebDialog solution ... is there a native one ? I hate that ugly Web window.

Comment: The feed dialog has a "to" field, allowing you to set the userid of a friend.

Comment: hi, the page seems to have been removed by facebook. could you please tell me how to share a post on a frnds wall using android sdk?

Answer (score 2):

You could use: [Send Request](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/send-requests/), if that fulfills your need. It's a native one too, but wont post on the wall. If you want to post on the wall as a feed, you have to use `Feed Dialog` only, and make a controller for the friends list by your own (or third party).